# realpath tells me my directory doesn't exist, but it does

Tags: shell, busybox, nixos

I don't understand this behaviour of the `realpath` command.

```
$ touch wombat
$ ls
wombat
$ cd /home/amy/test
$ ls
wombat
$ realpath --relative-to=. /home/amy/test/wombat
realpath: --relative-to=.: No such file or directory
/home/amy/test/wombat
$ realpath --relative-to=/home/amy/test /home/amy/test/wombat
realpath: --relative-to=/home/amy: No such file or directory
/home/amy/test/wombat
```

I expected both of those commands to return `wombat`. However, they seem to be telling me that the directory I'm in, or its parent, doesn't exist. It even tells me that the root directory doesn't exist.

```
$ realpath --relative-to=/ /home/amy/test/wombat
realpath: --relative-to=: No such file or directory
/home/amy/test/wombat
```

I discovered this because some code I wrote recently stopped working, so perhaps the behaviour of `realpath` has changed?

```
$ uname -a
Linux nixos 5.4.79 #1-NixOS SMP Sun Nov 22 09:14:12 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

*Edit:* OK, this is getting strange. Might be a problem with my latest NixOS upgrade.

```
$ realpath --version
realpath: --version: No such file or directory
```

---

*Edit:* Curiouser and curiouser.

```
$ tar --version
tar (busybox) 1.31.1
$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
$ realpath -P
realpath: -P: No such file or directory
$ realpath --physical
realpath: --physical: No such file or directory
```

---

*Edit:*

```
$ type realpath
realpath is /run/current-system/sw/bin/realpath
```

This looks normal for NixOS. For example:

```
$ type tar
tar is /run/current-system/sw/bin/tar
```

---

*Edit:* I think I might have an idea. I recently added busybox to my NixOS packages. Based on the output below, I think that supplies a simpler version of `realpath` that doesn't have the bells and whistles I'm used to.

```
$ realpath --help
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: realpath FILE...

Return the absolute pathnames of given FILE
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116836/discussion-on-question-by-mhwombat-realpath-tells-me-my-directory-doesnt-exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @thanasisp, @crtl-alt-delor, and @ilkkachu, I was able to figure out the problem. The light bulb moment was when I tried the following command:

```
$ realpath --help
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: realpath FILE...

Return the absolute pathnames of given FILE
```

This told me two things: 1) that I was running the BusyBox version of this command, and 2) that version of `realpath` doesn't support any of the command switches that I had been using.

I then recalled that one of the changes that I had made between the last time the command worked for me and now was to install BusyBox. Once I uninstalled BusyBox, I got the regular version of `realpath`, which worked as expected.

This was on NixOS, but I don't know that the problem is specific to NixOS.